# JASIG External Redirect in AuthenticationHandler

Tags: java, spring, cas, jasig

I'm at the end of my rope here and figure someone here might be able to help me. I'm working with the newest versions of JASIG CAS and Java and I've hit a wall.
I have an implementation of an AuthenticationHandler and I'm trying to redirect to an external URL on authentication failure. I can't figure out how to get a RequestContext (to use WebUtils.getHttpServletResponse(context)) in the Handler or to set a flowscope variable in the login-webflow.xml because I'm not calling the handler from the webflow.

I need to craft the URL for each specific failure because it includes an error code in the redirect so, I'm genuinely stumped. Does anyone have any places to point me or ideas on how I can accomplish my redirection?

Thanks for anyone who can give some tips!